# Не запускается .class через CMD

Tags: cmd, javac

Через командную строку не выполняется `имя_файла.class`, 
т.е. создаю файл с методом `main`, все как положено, `имя_файла.java`
в cmd пишу

```
javac имя_файла.java
```

компилируется и создается файл `имя_файла.class`
затем пишу

```
java имя_файла
```

выдает *Could not find or load main class* ...

через IDE - все компилируется и запускается.
п.с.: имя файла это для примера, оригинальное название Game

в `CLASSPATH` вписан путь к `jdk 1.8\bin`

```
public class Game{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("WOOOWWW!!!");
  }
}
```

Comment: А покажите, как класс написан

Comment: У класса точно дефолтный пакет? Есть нет, то его нужно указать при запуске.